# How to get request headers for the Apollo GraphQL error?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I need to get the request header on the client when an error occurs

```js
const { data, error } = useQuery(gql`Query ...`);

// ..
if (error) {
  // get the request headers here
  // e.g. error.graphQLErrors[0].headers.requestId
}
```

I was trying to modify the error using `onError` link but this object is Read Only

```
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';

const errorLink = onError((errorHandler) => {
  errorHandler.graphQLErrors[0].extensions = { requestId: ... }
})
```

I know I can extend `extensions` on the backend side but I need to generate the request ID on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example similar to what you're describing on the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/advanced-http-networking/#customizing-request-logic). It doesn't use extensions specifically, but would enable you to generate the request ID mentioned.

Comment: Yes this way you can generate the request ID, but you can't get it later when a query results in an error.